# Elasticsearch error when same search query

Tags: elasticsearch

Now i am working with Elastic search.But when i run same query for search,i can not get  same results.
First query:"GET /mega/employee/_search?q=last_name:Smith"
Result:I only get 2 results that "last_name==Smith"
Second query:

```html
"GET /mega/employee/_search
{
    "query" : {
        "match" : {
            "last_name" : "Smith"
        }
    }
}"
```

I get 3 results,with last result:last_name==Fer
Someones can explain for me?

Comment: When i run query in Marvel/Sense,i get same results.But in some other plugins : elatic-search-head or elasticsearch-kopf,i can not get true result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to POST to `_search`. GET with a body is ill-supported (and, I'd argue, meaningless according to the spec), and is rather abused by Elasticsearch. Your request is almost certainly being interpreted at a GET to your `_search` endpoint with no query attached.

Comment: but why right result in Sense,but error with other plugin:elatic-search-head or elasticsearch-kopf??

Comment: Sense is probably automatically sending a POST when it knows a GET won't work.

Comment: Yeah.I see.With post method,we can get right result.So with all of search queries,we should use POST method?